# How center widget behave as a parent?

Tags: flutter

By default,**center widget** take its child and center it in itself.But in my case it is not working.
I want to center my Column which contain multiple rows so we rap our column in a center widget.
Center widget should take column as a child and center it.But its behave unexpectedly.

Here is my code

```
        child: Column(
        
          children: <Widget>[

            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                //This is widget 1

                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    "Spice Jet",
                    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                      fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                      fontSize: 35.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                //This is widget 2

                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    "From Mubabi to Banglore via New dehli",
                    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                      fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),

            
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                //This is widget 1

                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    "Air India",
                    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                      fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                      fontSize: 35.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                //This is widget 2
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    "From Jaipur to Goa",
                    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                      fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[output of this code on emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bCBq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row has crossAxisAlignment to center as default. But when you wrap it into a column,
it doesnot appear in center because it has default crossAxisAlignment as start, not center. You will have to manually add this line :

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center
```

Your code should be like this :

```
....
color: Colors.deepPurple,
    child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center
      children: <Widget>[

        Row(
          children: <Widget>[....
```

Hope it helps! Happy coding:)

Answer (score 1):

Try using axis alignments.

For Row,

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center
```

For Column,

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center
```